# How to destruct C++ class inside package.preload function

Tags: c++, class, lua, swig, destructor

I'm using C++ classes in Lua which I wrapped using SWIG.

Since I'm using a single `Lua_State`, I would like to be able to free variables in a specific chunk of Lua script without calling `lua_close(L)`.

I decided to use `package.preload['name']` so a chunk can be accessed from other chunk by using `require 'name'` when needed.

And I was told that the variables inside `package.preload` function are freed after I do the following:

```
package.preload['name'] = nil
package.loaded['name'] = nil
```

However, it seems my custom C++ classes are not destructed even after this.

Here's my full example code:

In `Main.cpp`

```
#include "Main.h"

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['test'] = function ()\n"
                         "local test = {}\n"
                         "local class = my.Class()\n"
                         "return test\n"
                     "end\n");
    luaL_dostring(L, "require 'test'");
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['test'] = nil\n"
                     "package.loaded['test'] = nil\n");
}
```

In `Main.h`

```
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C"
{
    int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);
}
int main();
```

In `MyBindings.h`

```
#include "Main.h"

class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Class Constructed" << std::endl;
    };
    ~Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Class Destructed" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

In `MyBindings.i` (SWIG interface to generate `MyBindings.cpp`)

```
%module my
%{
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include <stl.i>
%include <typemaps.i>

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**Result :**

```
Class Constructed
```

Why is class destructor not called and how to correctly destruct classes and variables inside `package.preload` function?

Comment: The signature and the `extern "C"` declaration of `main` are not valid C++ (1) “[...] it shall have a declared return type of type int [...]” http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2 (2) “A program that declares [...] the name main with C language linkage (in any namespace) is ill-formed.” http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for pointing it out. I'm sorry I made a mistake when simplifying the code for this question. I edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem but you have other shortcomings in your code, most notably the absence of header guards.  The file `Main.h` is not necessary and even less so in the `MyBindings.h` file because it doesn't make use of it.  I don't know which compiler you are using but `void main()` is not valid C++, the standard dictates [`int main()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2).

**`Main.cpp`**

```
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C" int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['test'] = function ()\n"
                         "local test = {}\n"
                         "local class = my.Class()\n"
                         "return test\n"
                     "end\n");
    luaL_dostring(L, "require 'test'");
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['test'] = nil\n"
                     "package.loaded['test'] = nil\n");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

**`MyBindings.h`**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Class Constructed" << std::endl;
    };
    ~Class()
    {
        std::cout << "Class Destructed" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

**`MyBindings.i`**

```
%module my
%{
#include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -c++ -lua MyBindings.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2 -fPIC -shared MyBindings_wrap.cxx -o my.so -llua5.2
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2 -L . Main.cpp -l:my.so -llua5.2
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out 
Class Constructed
Class Destructed
```

---

Also you should note that Lua is a garbage collected language, i.e. destructors will run when the garbage collector thinks it is necessary.  You can run the garbage collector manually using [`lua_gc`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_gc) in C or using [`collectgarbage`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage) in Lua but **I strongly advise against running the garbage collector manually** as this usually impacts performance negatively (even though you ran it manually hoping to increase performance).  It only pays off to use the garbage collector manually when you are running in an environment with *very* limited memory and you have just pruned a table or something like that.

Anyway, I have prepared an example in Lua for you using the `my.so` module compiled above.

```lua
local my = require("my")
local x = my.Class()
print("Info: Deleting x")
x = nil
print("Info: Collecting garbage")
collectgarbage()
print("Info: Done :-)")
```

```
$ lua5.2 test.lua
Class Constructed
Info: Deleting x
Info: Collecting garbage
Class Destructed
Info: Done :-)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason you couldn't reproduce my problem is because you have `lua_close(L);` which will probably free all assigned memory. What I would like to do is only free memory inside a specific chunk of Lua script(free variables inside `package.preload` function) Is it not possible to manually do this in C++?

Comment: @ZackLee First of all, you should **always call `lua_close(L)`** before exiting your program.  I explained to you in the second part of the answer how to call the garbage collector manually.  How much memory does the machine your program is running on have?

Comment: @ZackLee Your are using the C-API, so you could equivalently call `lua_gc (L, LUA_GCCOLLECT, /*unused*/ 0);` to save the cost of string parsing and no, this is not a solution to your memory problems (if you even have any which I strongly doubt).

Comment: Also calling `collectgarbage()` is **not a substitute for `lua_close(L)`**!  Don't quit your program without!

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I will give you a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the d'tor explicitly byt obj.~class().
If you are using external classes in Lua wrapper, I'm not sire they can follow the correct nested d'tor paradigm which exists in C++.